# Iterate through a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

Very simple problem. Sorry I am new. I have this code below:

```
list = ['edward', 'jason', 'john']
for i in list:
    print list
```

and it produces:

```
john
```

Why do I only get the last name? I want all of them. ie.

```
edward
jason
john
```

Comment: No, it won't. It produces `['edward', 'jason', 'john']` three times. Looks like you mixed up some more variables in your code somewhere, because even if you used `i` instead, you'd get the 3 separate names on separate lines, never just one name.

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: What do you mean my actual code?

Comment: @Danrex Your code should output [this](http://ideone.com/5BXkZr) not `John.`

Comment: You are right it does.

Answer (score 5):

You should print `i` not `list`:

```
lis = ['edward', 'jason', 'john']    #don't use list as a variable name
for i in lis:
    print i
```

Comment: But even using lis I still only get the last name. I am wondering why I can't get it to iterate through the whole list and give me three names.

Comment: @Danrex did you use `print i`?

Comment: print i gives me J...so it starts from the last name and I don't get why?

Comment: @Danrex Post your original data then. For the data you've posted you can't get `J` as an output.